# Recursion in Mathematica

Tags: recursion, wolfram-mathematica

Can anyone explain to me how do I use a recursion, if I don't know the limit. For example, I need the remainder r of the Euclidean algorithm for gcd(a,b) which equals 0. I figured out that the recursive formula I need is

```
r[n]=r[n-2]-Floor[r[n-2]/r[n-1] * r[n-1] 

r[1] = a - Floor[a/b]*  b;
r[2] = b - Floor[b/r1] r1;
```

Comment: your first function should be defined as `r[n_] := ..`

Comment: and the `r1` in the last line should i guess be `r[1]`